# Indirect showing error while adding new sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a sheet for my office work, in that I have created a summary page for one month, Sheet name should be 1 to 31. But now I only have sheet 1, IN summary page I have created indirect formula by taking data from each sheet from a particular cell, since sheet "1" is there the valve is coming but when I create other sheets say "2", "3", the valve is not coming and error coming as #REF!, I know it will come as sheets are not there, but when I create the sheet and data entered still it is showing error and not getting auto update.

Say for example: I have used formula for day 1 sum(indirect("'"&row(A1)&"'!C23"),indirect("'"&row(A1)&"'!I23")) and day 2 as sum(indirect("'"&row(A2)&"'!C23"),indirect("'"&row(A2)&"'!I23")) and so on till 31. But the sheet I will be creating only on the particular date and enter the data, and in that case I am not getting value, in other words not getting auto update

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a  sample spreadsheet?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I found solution, I done force refresh using now function. Thanks again